# how can I select all of my columns and select sum of all salaries next to it?

Tags: sql

```
id | first_name | salary  
-------------------------------
1  | Hamdi      | 100
------------------------------
2  | Abdo       | 100
-----------------------------
3  | Haji       | 100
```

here is the output I expect.

```
id | first_name | salary | sum(salary)
--------------------------------------
1  | Hamdi      | 100    | 300
-------------------------------------
2  | Abdo       | 100    |
-------------------------------------
3  | Haji       | 100    |
```

So, how can I get that summation?.

Comment: That's your 3rd question about the very same thing, and you have been given numerous answers. If this is about CakePHP (its certainly not about regular expressions - please mind your tags), then please explain in what way. If it's not about CakePHP, then this seems to be just another duplicate.

Comment: It's not about CakePHP really, but I couldn't do that summation with the group by, So I asked  and I don't remember asking like this question and have no answer for it, and i would be really greateful if I get and answer,Sorry for disturbance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify which database you are targeting.

I also could not understand the need for total_summary on only first row. Please note that the answers below gives result for all rows.

here is the code for Oracle Database (similar approach works for most of the modern RDBMS systems)

```
select id, first_name, salary,
sum(salary) over ()
from table1
```

In MySql you need to use something like this, since it does not support over() clause

```
select id, first_name, salary,
  (select SUM(salary) from Table1) total
from Table1
```

**EDIT:** For only first row. You can initialize @row_number variable and use it in case by incrementing and checking for the first row

```
SET @row_number = 0;
select id, first_name, salary,
  case when (@row_number:=@row_number +1) = 1 then (select SUM(salary) from Table1)
  else null end as total
from Table1
```

similarly

```
SET @row_number = 0;
select id, first_name, salary,
  case when (@row_number:=@row_number +1) = 1 then (sum(salary) over ()) as total
  else null end total
from Table1
```

Comment: the first query worked but duplicating the same number in all records, I want that summation to be in one record if possible

Comment: Which Database are you using?